# Entire image link with a section of the image mapped elsewhere

Tags: html, image, src

When you link an entire image like in the HTML code below, can you still use image mapping to link a specific area on that image to a different address than what would be specified in the code below. For example, I have an image here: http://joshuamcauley.zxq.net/products/gloves/FBG2.png that when the user clicks on it a pop-up box appears with more information about the product. I was wondering if I used an image mapping program, can I make the Buy Now area add the product to the shopping cart or would the general link of the entire image over-ride this?

HTML

```
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `linking part of the image to a different link?` ???

Comment: Edited Op to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be achieved by the html's `map` tag, so that you can map a particular section of the image to a specific href/perform different tasks.

**[Tutorial-HTML Map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)** may be helpful to you on this.

Hope this is what you are looking for.